# Box shadow not working in microsoft edge

Tags: html, css

Box-shadow not working on Microsoft Edge browser. I have implemented the follow in the  section: (I'm not an idiot I have  at the top)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This is the **body** of my index.html file:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div id="header-inner">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="index.html">body</a>
                </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="sign-in" href="#">Sign in</a>
                    <span id="sign-in-menu">
                        <div class="arrow-up"></div>
                        <div class="arrow-up-top"></div>

                        <div class="form">
                            <form action="login.php" method="get">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="inputUser">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password"
                            name="inputPass">
                            <!-- <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="css-checkbox">
                                <label for="checkboxG1" class="css-label">Remember me</label> COOOKKiiieeesss -->
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="submit-area">
                            <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li><a href="register.html">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

The hover CSS box shadow code:

```
header li > span input[type=submit]:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
}
```

Comment: If you dont have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your code, please add it

Comment: why??? its at the very beginning and is standard practice.

Comment: @Justinas, comment edited.. Actually I mean to add it

Comment: Maybe your selector is wrong? I don't see any `header`, `li` or `span` in your code

Comment: I am aware of that @Justinas that is not what I am concerned about. I have it in a header and li and all that. I am asking why the hover is not working even though I have the doctype, x-ua-compatible and the -ms- thing on box shadow

Comment: Not sure why people are down voting this, question seems pretty clear to me

Comment: Show doctype, and structure from `header` till `<input type="submit">`

Answer (score 2):

Either change the css to:

```
header li > a > span input[type=submit]:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
}
```

or

```
header li span input[type=submit]:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #383e46;
}
```

You have put an `>` between the `li` and `span` however the `span` never appears directly after the `li` within the code structure. Instead you either need to specify the `a` tag in your css like in my first example or remove the `>` to remove the specificity like in my second example.

Comment: thank-you for that but unfortunately this does not help my case and in fact my css gets butchered left and right from Microsoft Edge. I changed it and it is the same. Still no box shadow.