# Keep background color after selection when in focus Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

I have a select form in Bootstrap 4 with dark background, when I select an option I want the background after selection to stay dark. My example works in Chrome and Firefox. But in IE and Edge the background stays white while in focus. Check my jsfiddle, any ideas?

```
.form-control:focus {
  background-color: #121212;
  border-color: #121212;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cd1eyqvr/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the `.form-control:focus` part and add this in your css:

```
.form-control:focus::-ms-value {
        background-color: #242424 !important;
        border-color: #121212 !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
        outline: 0 !important;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
    }
```

This part will work in IE11 and Edge.

You can refer to the demo I made: https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/ofwvuzyr/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check this link from offical docs:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/

It seems the edge has problems with **box shadow** and you must add extra css to your stylesheet Check the links blow for more help about your problem [Box shadow not working in microsoft edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867235/box-shadow-not-working-in-microsoft-edge)

And also check this link for complete **box shadow in edge** solutions

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, but according to the docs latest versions of IE and Edge are supported, or did I misss something? form-control:active does not make a difference, background is still white

Comment: I got the solution from Yu Zhou but thanks for the links